# Checkbox data to firebase

Tags: android, firebase, checkbox, firebase-realtime-database

How can I add checkbox values to my firebase database?
Now I'm using edittext to store an item in the database. I want it to be checkable with a checkbox. And that it saves the checkboxes state even if I restart my app.

I've searched for an answer here, but no luck:(
So I'm trying to ask for my self.

Model class:

```
public class Items {

String itemId;
String itemname;

public items(){


}

public Items (String itemId, String itemname){
    this.itemId = itemId;
    this.itemname = itemname;

}

public String getItemId() {
    return itemId;
}

public String getItemname() {
    return itemname;
}
```

Adapter:

```
public class listItems extends ArrayAdapter<Items> {

private Activity context;
private List<Items> listitems;



public listItems(Activity context, List<Items> listitems){
    super (context, R.layout.list_items, listitems);
    this.context = context;
    this.listitems = listitems;

}
@NonNull
@Override
public View getView(final int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();


    View listViewItem = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_items, null, true);

    TextView tvitemname = (TextView) listViewItem.findViewById(R.id.tvitemname);
    CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox) listViewItem.findViewById(R.id.checkbx);



    Items items = listitems.get(position);

    tvitemname.setText(items.getItemname());






    return listViewItem;
}
```

Add item activity

```
 private void additem(){
    String itemname = etitemname.getText().toString().trim();


    if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(itemname)) {

        String id = databaseItems.push().getKey();

        Item item = new Item (id, itemname);

        databaseItems.child(id).setValue(item);

        Toast.makeText(this, "Item added", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


    } else {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Itemname missing...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }
}
```

}

Comment: Hard to understand what you want?

Comment: Ok, I save data in firebase now, and retrieve it in a listview in my app. What I want is to add a checkbox beside my itemname that I can check or uncheck.

Comment: Implement `onItemClickListener` in your activity then.

Comment: But my checkbox is in the list_item layout. How can I implement `onItemClickListener` in my activity when it's not in my activity layout? Should I implement it in my getview?

Comment: It doesn't necessarily have to get saved in firebase. I just want it to be saved, so when I restart my app, it will be the same value (checked, unchecked) that it was before I restart my app.

Comment: Have tried saving the database value as `boolean`?

Comment: I've tried that, but then I get problems with my additem activity. I've edited my code to show you where I get these problems. It is with this line `Item item = new Item (id, itemname);`